# Cannot open HPROF file

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory

I'm using Eclipse Indigo and I'm following [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyser/article.html) tutorial, after I run the example project and get my HPROF file, I tried to open it (see 3.3 Use MAT in the link I gave), I just keep receiving 'Out of Memory' error. I checked the file generated and its size is about 350MB. So I edited the eclipse.ini file to add more memory (I changed -xmx to 1024m), also did the same for the java app in run->run configurations. But no mather what number I give to -xmx I'm still getting the same heap space error. Any ideas? or is there any other tool that I can use?

Comment: please try also by increasing the MaxPermSize. I have parsed 1+ GB sized heap dumps using MAT in the past, so its definitely a configuration issue at your end. One more thing, I typically manage memory settings through command line / shortcut (e.g.  -vmargs -Xmx1024M).

Answer (score 0):

In my eclipse.ini I use the following settings:

> -vmargs
>   -XX:PermSize=256m 
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
>   -Xms256m
>   -Xmx1024m

I am able to open big hprofs with some hundreds of megabytes.